# Wordpress Feed stuck in maintenance mode

Tags: wordpress, rss

I had activated maintenance mode on my site through the WP-maintenance mode plugin . After disabling the maintenance mode , my site's rss feed is still in maintenance mode. I emptied the W3TC cache and even added the disabled/deleted the plugin and cleaned the DB tables but the feed is still in mainteance mode . Kindly help me to resolve this issue .

My website's feed URL :- http://example.com/feed

Comment: Does disabling all plugins resolve the issue? Try this first and then enable all plugins one after another while always checking whether it still works.

Comment: Often it is a cache problem. The plugin have only a rewrite of the feed, if is active. No caching.

Answer (score 0):

i never used this pulgin. But i'm reading on internet that a lot of people have your same problem. Are u sure that u have cleaned the tables in the db? To do that try to use:
WP-Optimize

and the next time, for to switch in the maintenance mode do:

```
function maintenace_mode() {
      if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_themes' ) || !is_user_logged_in() ) {wp_die('Maintenance.');}
}
add_action('get_header', 'maintenace_mode');
```

in your functions.php theme file.